# ValueError: could not convert string to float in univariate_selection

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

Hello i'm using univariate_selection method for selecting a best features from a following data set:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J31T0.png

But i got an error
  `Value Error: could not convert string to float: 'SUDMyYggegA'`

Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
data = pd.read_csv("C://Users/Shahnawaz Irfan/Desktop/demo.csv")
X = data.iloc[:,0:15]  
y = data.iloc[:,-13]    
bestfeatures = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=10)
fit = bestfeatures.fit(X,y)
dfscores = pd.DataFrame(fit.scores_)
dfcolumns = pd.DataFrame(X.columns)
featureScores = pd.concat([dfcolumns,dfscores],axis=1)
featureScores.columns = ['features','Score']  
print(featureScores.nlargest(15,'Score'))  `
```

Comment: sklearn, as a general rule, cannot take text features. You need to process your text features into numeric before calling `.fit`

Comment: @G.Anderson, can you help me in this?

Comment: Unfortunately that question is too broad to be on-topic for this site. sklearn has a whole [section of the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) dedicated to handling text data, that would be a good place to start. Then, if you have _specific_ questions that you can provide a [mcve] for, then that would be a much better question for stack overflow

Comment: can you correct a line of code in which error occurs?

Comment: The error occurs because you are trying to pass text data into a function that can only handle numeric data. The solution is to pass your data in as numeric. Unfortunately, beyond that, you will need to research how to handle text data for your modeling